# In Spring Boot 2, is it possible to auto-generate a JoinTable with a unique constraint?

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, join

I'm using Spring Boot 2 and PostGres 10.  I have created the following entities, Roles and Privileges,

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Roles")
public class Role {
  
    public enum Name {
        USER,
        ADMIN
    }
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;
 
    @Column(unique=true)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Name name;
 
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "roles_privileges", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
          name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
          name = "privilege_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Collection<Privilege> privileges;   
}
```

Privilege is

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Privileges")
public class Privilege {

    public enum PrivilegeName {
        SUPER_ADMIN,
        USER
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;
    
    @Column(unique=true)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private PrivilegeName name;
 
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "privileges")
    private Collection<Role> roles;
}
```

Then I have this in my application.properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${PG_DB_HOST:localhost}:5432/${PG_DB_NAME}

spring.datasource.username=${PG_DB_USER}
spring.datasource.password=${PG_DB_PASS}
```

When my tables are generated, the roles_privileges table is generated like so ...

```
cardmania=# \d roles_privileges ;
 Table "public.roles_privileges"
    Column    | Type | Modifiers 
--------------+------+-----------
 role_id      | uuid | not null
 privilege_id | uuid | not null
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk5duhoc7rwt8h06avv41o41cfy" FOREIGN KEY (privilege_id) REFERENCES privileges(id)
    "fk629oqwrudgp5u7tewl07ayugj" FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES roles(id)
```

Are there any other annotations or other Java code I can add so that when my join table is created, the role_id/privilege_id has a unique key generated?

Comment: In many to many relationships role_id or privilege_id can't be unique, but they are composite  unique

Comment: Correct -- this is the case for my situation as well.  They are composite unique.  However, I notice when my join table is auto-generated, this composite unique constraint is not created.  I was curious if there's a way to make that happen given my set up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To force Hibernate to create a primary key with both columns, you have to change `Collection` by `Set`

```
public class Role {
  
  @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
  @JoinTable(
    name = "roles_privileges",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
       name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
       name = "privilege_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
  private Set<Privilege> privileges;
  
}
```

And:

```
public class Privilege {
  
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "privileges")
  private Set<Role> roles;
  
}
```

[image: Autogenerated primary key]

Comment: This is a better solution than mine

Comment: This would be my preferred solution (having a composite primary key). However, please be aware that the runtime behavior will be different depending on whether or not you have a working / correct implementation of equals() / hashCode() implemented. A Set would simply ignore the request to re-add a duplicate (according to your equals / hashCode implementation) to the set whereas a Collection would accept a duplicated element and then be rejected via the DB constraint.

Answer (score 0):

- You will not see a unique constraint but you will see the following table

```
   create table roles_privileges (
       role_id binary not null,
       privilege_id binary not null
   )
```

- But you can explicitly declare your unique constraint

```
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
       name = "roles_privileges",
       joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
       inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "privilege_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
       uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"role_id", 
                                                        "privilege_id"},
                    name = "rolesPrivilegesConstraint")
    )
    private Collection<Privilege> privileges;
```

Comment: Again almost "at the same time" ;)

Comment: But answers are from different perspectives. So good to know

Comment: And strictly speaking, this is exactly what he asked for, though a composite primary key is a better long-term solution (IMO).